# Free modules and ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

I am trying to show that an ideal I of R=$\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]$ generated by $x_1, x_2$ is free R-module. I am trying to show that I has a basis of the two generators given above. But I am not able to show the linear independence part.

Also, does this result generalize for arbitrary number of variables?

Comment: It's not true that the ideal $(x_1, x_2) \subseteq \mathbb C[x_1, x_2]$ is a free $\mathbb C[x_1, x_2]$-module.  The fact that it's not true *does* generalize to an arbitrary number of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ideals that cannot be generated by two elements! For example, let $I_n$ be the ideal of all linear combinations of monomials of total degree $n$ or more. e.g. $I_2 = \langle x_1^2, x_1 x_2, x_2^2 \rangle$

It's easy to see that $I_2 / I_3$ is a three-dimensional vector space over $\mathbf{C}$; its elements are in one-to-one correspondence with the polynomials that have monomials of only total degree 2. Furthermore, if you have a set of generators for $I_2/I_3$ (as an ideal over $\mathbf{C}[x_1,x_2]/I_3$), the elements of of $I_2/I_3$ are simply the $\mathbf{C}$-linear combinations of the generators. Thus, any generating set for $I_2 / I_3$ requires a minimum of three elements.

And thus, the same goes for $I_2$.

---

*Prime* ideals can be generated by two elements, though.